# Wget cookie session set to DUMMY, 302 redirect issue?

Tags: session-cookies, wget, http-status-code-302

Been reading here for years, love it. Time for my own little question.

We used to retrieve product info (prices, availability) from our suppliers'backend using wget SSH. They changed their ways unfortunately, crippling my dataflow:/

I have fixed it somewhat, but i cannot get all data since my cookie is not stored well anymore. Read all Google results, tried them all but my knowledge is lacking. I'll stick to the cookie setting part, i bet if that is fixed, i can retrieve all files again in good order too.

Here's what i use, i have no reputation points so i cannot add more than one link, i will use 'url-here' as a substitute to my https://www.supplier.com

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -O /dev/null --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=cookies.txt --post-data='login=123654&password=123654&from=%2F' 'url-here/auth/login.php'
```

The cookie gives this:

```
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2013-07-25 06:03:44.
# Edit at your own risk.

www.supplier.com    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   DUMMY
```

A cookie via the browser shows a value for the session, this part does not seem to be written anymore:/

Also tried this, all with the same result:

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -O /dev/null --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookiepp.txt --referer='url-here/auth/login.php' --post-data='login=123654&password=123654' 'url-here/auth/login.php'
```

And also tried this to retireve directly with a manually saved cookie:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --span-hosts --header "Cookie:PHPSESSID=h771tqr0spe8ufbq6fash2msf6" "url-here/sortment/s/?group="$i"&excel=1"
```

Finally, the ssh command line flow:

```
--2013-07-25 06:03:43--  https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Resolving www.supplier.com (www.supplier.com)... 00.000.000.0
Connecting to www.supplier.com (www.supplier.com)|00.000.000.0|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php [following]
--2013-07-25 06:03:44--  https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Reusing existing connection to www.supplier.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6884 (6.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: '/dev/null'
```

Last, the debug info:

```
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to /dev/null
Setting --cookies (cookies) to on
Setting --keep-session-cookies (keepsessioncookies) to 1
Setting --save-cookies (savecookies) to cookiepp.txt
Setting --referer (referer) to https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Setting --post-data (postdata) to login=123654&password=123654
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.14 on freebsd9.1.

URI encoding = 'US-ASCII'
--2013-07-25 07:01:30--  https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Resolving www.supplier.com (www.supplier.com)... 89.105.214.133
Caching www.supplier.com => 89.105.214.133
Connecting to www.supplier.com (www.supplier.com)|89.105.214.133|:443... connected.
Created socket 5.
Releasing 0x00000008021baa40 (new refcount 1).
Initiating SSL handshake.
Handshake successful; connected socket 5 to SSL handle 0x000000080204c400
certificate:
  subject: /C=NL/postalCode=7271LB/ST=Gelderland/L=Borculo/street=Hesselinks Es 11/O=Varuvo bv/OU= /OU=Hosted by WideXS/OU=InstantSSL/CN=www.supplier.com
  issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA
X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host www.supplier.com

---request begin---
POST /auth/login.php HTTP/1.1
Referer: https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (freebsd9.1)
Accept: */*
Host: www.supplier.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

---request end---
[POST data: login=123654&password=123654]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 14:01:32 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID CURa OUR NOR STA"
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=DUMMY; path=/
Status: 302 Found
Location: https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252

---response end---
302 Found

Stored cookie www.supplier.com -1 (ANY) / <session> <insecure> [expiry none] PHPSESSID DUMMY
Registered socket 5 for persistent reuse.
URI content encoding = 'Windows-1252'
Location: https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php [following]
] done.
URI content encoding = None
--2013-07-25 07:01:31--  https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
Reusing existing connection to www.supplier.com:443.
Reusing fd 5.

---request begin---
GET /auth/login.php HTTP/1.1
Referer: https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
User-Agent: Wget/1.14 (freebsd9.1)
Accept: */*
Host: www.supplier.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=DUMMY

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 14:01:32 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID CURa OUR NOR STA"
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=DUMMY; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 6884
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252

---response end---
200 OK
Deleted old cookie (to be replaced.)

Stored cookie www.supplier.com -1 (ANY) / <session> <insecure> [expiry none] PHPSESSID DUMMY
URI content encoding = 'Windows-1252'
Length: 6884 (6.7K) [text/html]
Saving to: '/dev/null'

100%[===================================================================================================================>] 6,884       43.1KB/s   in 0.2s

2013-07-25 07:01:32 (43.1 KB/s) - '/dev/null' saved [6884/6884]

Saving cookies to cookiepp.txt.
Done saving cookies.
```

I really am lost with this, I'd love some help from others at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it using cURL:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl -k -c cookie.txt -d "login_alias=464" -d "password=6446" -d "from=%2F" https://www.supplier.com/auth/login.php
paste theCodesOnePerLine theNamesOnePerLine |
while read i j
do 
/usr/local/bin/curl -k -L -b cookie.txt -o /usr/home/$j.xls 'https://www.supplier.com/?group='$i'&excel=1'
done
```

Thanks though, for page space:p